# Delimited text output in jsPDF

Tags: jspdf

Is it possible to delimit the length of text using jsPDF?

Ex.: I need to write some dots at every item:

```
Apples: .............................. $10.00
Grapefruit: .......................... $20.00
```

My current code:

```
doc.text(x, y, product + ".............................." + value);
```

This gives the following result:

```
Apples: .............................. $10.00
Grapefruit: .............................. $20.00
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementation to repeat the dot "n" number of times to make the length equal. Here I have calculated the length and reduced it from a finite length and added the number of dots with the resulting value.

`doc.text(x, y, product + " " + Array(44-(product.length+value.length)).join(".") + " " + value);`

Comment: But I´m using a not fixed size font.

Comment: So one way to do this is you need to measure the width of the text and add the number of dots like I mentioned in the answer but this time based on width of text. There are methods in jsPDF for this purpose :
`doc.getStringUnitWidth()` and `doc.getTextWidth()`
[Here is the link to the issue on github](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/67)